# How do I convert multiple JSON files with unidentical structure to a single pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

The input is many JSON files differing in structure, and the desired output is a single dataframe.

**Input Description:**

*Each* JSON file may have 1 or many attackers and exactly 1 victim. The `attackers` key points to a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary is 1 attacker with keys such as `character_id`, `corporation_id`, `alliance_id`, etc. The `victim` key points to dictionary with similar keys. Important thing to note here is that the keys might differ between the same JSON. For example, a JSON file may have `attackers` key which looks like this:

```
{
    "attackers": [
        {
            "alliance_id": 99005678,
            "character_id": 94336577,
            "corporation_id": 98224639,
            "damage_done": 3141,
            "faction_id": 500003,
            "final_blow": true,
            "security_status": -9.4,
            "ship_type_id": 73796,
            "weapon_type_id": 3178
        },
        {
            "damage_done": 1614,
            "faction_id": 500003,
            "final_blow": false,
            "security_status": 0,
            "ship_type_id": 32963
        }
    ],
...
```

Here the JSON file has 2 attackers. But only the first attacker has the afore-mentioned keys. Similarly, the `victim` may look like this:

```
...
"victim": {
        "character_id": 2119076173,
        "corporation_id": 98725195,
        "damage_taken": 4755,
        "faction_id": 500002,
        "items": [...
...
```

**Output Description:**

As an output I want to create a dataframe from many (about 400,000) such JSON files stored in the same directory. Each row of the resulting dataframe should have 1 attacker and 1 victim. JSONs with multiple attackers should be split into equal number of rows, where the attackers' properties are different, but the victim properties are the same. For e.g., 3 rows if there are 3 attackers and `NaN` values where a certain attacker doesn't have a key-value pair. So, the `character_id` for the second attacker in the dataframe of the above example should be `NaN`.

**Current Method:**

To achieve this, I first create an empty list. Then iterate through all the files, open them, load them as JSON objects, convert to dataframe then append dataframe to the list. Please note that `pd.DataFrame([json.load(fi)])` has the same output as `pd.json_normalize(json.load(fi))`.

```
mainframe = []

for file in tqdm(os.listdir("D:/Master/killmails_jul"), ncols=100, ascii='          >'):
    with open("%s/%s" % ("D:/Master/killmails_jul", file),'r') as fi:
        mainframe.append(pd.DataFrame([json.load(fi)]))
```

After this loop, I am left with a list of dataframes which I concatenate using `pd.concat()`.

```
mainframe = pd.concat(mainframe)
```

As of yet, the dataframe only has 1 row per JSON irrespective of the number of `attackers`. To fix this, I use `pd.explode()` in the next step.

```
mainframe = mainframe.explode('attackers')
mainframe.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Now I have separate rows for each attacker, however the `attackers` & `victim` keys are still hidden in their respective column. To fix this I 'explode' the the two columns horizontally by `pd.apply(pd.Series)` and apply prefix for easy recognition as follows:

```
intframe = mainframe["attackers"].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("attackers_").join(mainframe["victim"].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("victim_"))
```

In the next step I join this intermediate frame with the mainframe to retain the `killmail_id` and `killmail_hash` columns. Then remove the `attackers` & `victim` columns as I have now expanded them.

```
mainframe = intframe.join(mainframe)
mainframe.fillna(0, inplace=True)
mainframe.drop(['attackers','victim'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This gives me the desired output with the following 24 columns:

['attackers_character_id', 'attackers_corporation_id', 'attackers_damage_done', 'attackers_final_blow', 'attackers_security_status', 'attackers_ship_type_id', 'attackers_weapon_type_id', 'attackers_faction_id', 'attackers_alliance_id', 'victim_character_id', 'victim_corporation_id', 'victim_damage_taken', 'victim_items', 'victim_position', 'victim_ship_type_id', 'victim_alliance_id', 'victim_faction_id', 'killmail_id', 'killmail_time', 'solar_system_id', 'killmail_hash', 'http_last_modified', 'war_id', 'moon_id']

**Question:**

Is there a better way to do this than I am doing right now? I tried to use generators but couldn't get them to work. I get an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`

```
all_files_paths = glob(os.path.join('D:\\Master\\kmrest', '*.json'))

def gen_df(files):
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r'):
            data = json.load(file)
        data = pd.DataFrame([data])
        yield data

mainframe = pd.concat(gen_df(all_files_paths), ignore_index=True)
```

Will using the `pd.concat()` function with generators lead to quadratic copying?
Also, I am worried opening and closing many files is slowing down computation. Maybe it would be better to create a JSONL file from all the JSONs first and then creating a dataframe for each line.

If you'd like to get your hands on the files, I am trying to work with you can click [here](https://data.everef.net/killmails/2022/killmails-2022-11-22.tar.bz2). Let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: What is the expected treatment of `items` for each victim?

Comment: @PierreD I don't have any use for the items, so I just leave it as a list of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pd.json_normalize()` to help with the heavy lifting:

First, load your data:

```py
import json
import requests
import tarfile
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

url = 'https://data.everef.net/killmails/2022/killmails-2022-11-22.tar.bz2'
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    fobj = io.BytesIO(r.raw.read())
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=fobj, mode='r:bz2') as tar:
        json_files = [it for it in tar if it.name.endswith('.json')]
        data = [json.load(tar.extractfile(it)) for it in tqdm(json_files)]
```

[image]

To do the same with your files:

```py
import json
from glob import glob

def json_load(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return json.load(f)

topdir = '...'  # the dir containing all your json files
data = [json_load(fn) for fn in tqdm(glob(f'{topdir}/*.json'))]
```

Once you have a list of dicts in `data`:

```py
others = ['killmail_id', 'killmail_hash']
a = pd.json_normalize(data, 'attackers', others, record_prefix='attackers.')
v = pd.json_normalize(data).drop('attackers', axis=1)
df = a.merge(v, on=others)
```

Some quick inspection:

```
>>> df.shape
(44903, 26)

# check:
>>> sum([len(d['attackers']) for d in data])
44903

>>> df.columns
Index(['attackers.alliance_id', 'attackers.character_id',
       'attackers.corporation_id', 'attackers.damage_done',
       'attackers.final_blow', 'attackers.security_status',
       'attackers.ship_type_id', 'attackers.weapon_type_id',
       'attackers.faction_id', 'killmail_id', 'killmail_hash', 'killmail_time',
       'solar_system_id', 'http_last_modified', 'victim.alliance_id',
       'victim.character_id', 'victim.corporation_id', 'victim.damage_taken',
       'victim.items', 'victim.position.x', 'victim.position.y',
       'victim.position.z', 'victim.ship_type_id', 'victim.faction_id',
       'war_id', 'moon_id'],
      dtype='object')

>>> df.iloc[:5, :5]
   attackers.alliance_id  attackers.character_id  attackers.corporation_id  attackers.damage_done  attackers.final_blow
0  99007887.0             1.450608e+09            2.932806e+08              1426                   False               
1  99010931.0             1.628193e+09            5.668252e+08              1053                   False               
2  99007887.0             1.841341e+09            1.552312e+09              1048                   False               
3  99007887.0             2.118406e+09            9.872458e+07               662                   False               
4  99005839.0             9.573650e+07            9.947834e+08               630                   False               

>>> df.iloc[-5:, -5:]
       victim.position.z  victim.ship_type_id  victim.faction_id  war_id  moon_id
44898  1.558110e+11       670                 NaN                NaN     NaN     
44899 -7.678686e+10       670                 NaN                NaN     NaN     
44900 -7.678686e+10       670                 NaN                NaN     NaN     
44901 -7.678686e+10       670                 NaN                NaN     NaN     
44902 -7.678686e+10       670                 NaN                NaN     NaN
```

Note also that, as desired, missing keys for attackers are `NaN`:

```py
>>> df.iloc[15:20, :2]
    attackers.alliance_id  attackers.character_id
15  99007887.0             2.117497e+09          
16  99011893.0             1.593514e+09          
17         NaN             9.175132e+07          
18         NaN             2.119191e+09          
19  99011258.0             1.258332e+09
```